# TextBox autocomplete and default buttons

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, autocomplete

I have a .NET TextBox with AutoComplete feature on the form. The form has also AcceptButton and CancelButton defined. If I try to commit a suggestion with Enter key or close drop down with Esc, my form closes. 
How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Do not assign AcceptButton and CancelButton form properties. Set DialogResult in the buttons OnClick event.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way is to remove **AcceptButton** and **CancelButton** properties while you are in auto-complete textbox:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        txtAuto.Enter +=txtAuto_Enter;
        txtAuto.Leave +=txtAuto_Leave;
    }

    private void txtAC_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AcceptButton = null;
        CancelButton = null;
    }

    private void txtAC_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AcceptButton = btnOk;
        CancelButton = btnCancel;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead to Accept and Cancel buttons you can go for the following approach:

1. Set **KeyPreview** property for the form to true.
2. Handle the **KeyDown** event of the form, in the handler method you can have something similar to the below code

   ```
   switch (e.KeyCode)
   {
       case Keys.Enter:
       {
           if (!txtAuto.Focused)
           {
               Save();
           }
           break;
       }
       case Keys.Escape:
       {
           if (!txtAuto.Focused)
           {
               Close();
           }
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: KeyDown event of the form won't be fired.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to derive your own custom TextBox class that performs validation when Enture/Return is pressed:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter || keyData == Keys.Return)
        {
            // Perform validation here
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```