# disable key event when the focus is on autocompletion box of textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, textbox, key-events

In my project there is a Form `mainForm` in which there are two textBoxes `txtUserName` and `txtPassword` and also a button `btnLogin`.

I have given the following `txtUserName` properties:

**txtUserName Properties**

```
AutoCompleteCustomSource - Collection
                            --> Administrator
                            --> Clerk
AutoCompleteMode   - Suggest
AutoCompleteSource - CustomSource
```

**btnLogin_Click Event**

```
if (txtUserName.Text.Equals("Administrator") && txtPassword.Text.Equals("123"))
{
    //function to access admin features
}
else if (txtUserName.Text.Equals("Clerk") && txtPassword.Text.Equals("123"))
{
    //function to access clerk features
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter correct details", "Login Error");
}
```

I have setted the `mainForm`  `keypreview` to `true` and implemented function to keyDown event of `mainForm` which is shown in the below code:

**mainForm_KeyDownEvent**

```
if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter))  //Invokes whenever Enter is pressed
{
    btnLogin_Click(sender,e);  //login
}
```

Now my problem is that whenever the focus is on `txtUserName` and pressing `A`, dropdown is showing to select "Administrator" (which is defined in collections as I shown in above properties). When I click `Enter` on keyboard it is showing MessageBox instead of selecting "Administrator". I know that is invoking the keydown event of `mainForm`. How to disable the keyDown event, when it is on textbox dropdown thing so that I can press `enter`?

**EDIT**:

 I tried the below code in `public form()` :(*not working*)

```
InitializeComponent();
if (txtUserName.AutoCompleteMode) { /* showing red scribbles */
            this.KeyDown -= mainForm_KeyDown;
        }
```

Comment: Can you afford pressing Down key before pressing Enter key to select suggested text?

Comment: sorry I cant understand what you are saying.

Comment: Before pressing enter key (while you are in txtUsername) you should press Down(arrow) Key to select the suggestedt option (provided by autocomplete source)

Comment: ya you are right but what can I do in that(still the problem stands)? If you have any idea please share in your answer eventhough it is not related or it is a alternative way. I think there is only one solution,  to get rid of the autocompletion thing and creating our own autocompletion function.

Comment: I have tested my answer it in your code. just please replace your Form_keyDown code and this time you even not need to press DownKey just write `a` or `c` and press enter.

Comment: If you are so much tolerant. Then you can get a lot of solutions from me for this case I have had long time troubles with these things. Every solution will be working at my side and at least one will work for you too :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextBox autocomplete and default buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068783/textbox-autocomplete-and-default-buttons)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be handling the Enter key at all. You can remove your `KeyDown` handler, and instead use the [`AcceptButton` property of the form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to set the button that gets "clicked" when Enter is pressed. This is already supposed to *not* "click" the button when another control has already handled the Enter key.

That isn't enough for your situation, because standard Windows behaviour *is* for the Enter key to press the default button. Press Win+R, for example, to get the Run... dialog, start typing C:\Use, press Down to select C:\Users, press Enter, and see what happens.

In order to override that behaviour, you need to make the text box tell the form that it will be handling the Enter key itself, so that the form won't send it to the default button. This can be done by creating a derived class and overriding `IsInputKey`:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        return base.IsInputKey(keyData) || ((keyData & ~Keys.Shift) == Keys.Enter && IsDroppedDown);
    }
}
```

However, `TextBox` implements autocompletion using the [`SHAutoComplete` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which automatically creates an [`IAutoComplete` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) behind the scenes. That object cannot be accessed, and because of that, the `IsDroppedDown` property that I used in `IsInputKey` cannot be created. It would be implemented using [`IAutoCompleteDropDown.GetDropDownStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776285%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but since the object is inaccessible, you cannot (reliably) determine whether the dropdown list is showing.

You would need to either implement the auto completion *without* using the built-in `AutoComplete*` properties, or you would need to *always* suppress the Enter key (remove the `&& IsDroppedDown` in the above `IsInputKey`).

**Update**: here's how to create an `IAutoComplete` object manually. The strings Administrator and Clerk are hardcoded. The GetDropDownStatus function is used to suppress any default button's handling of Enter when the drop down list is visible. Feedback welcome.

IAutoComplete.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

[ComImport]
[Guid("00bb2762-6a77-11d0-a535-00c04fd7d062")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[CoClass(typeof(IAutoCompleteClass))]
interface IAutoComplete
{
    void Init(HandleRef hwndEdit, IEnumString punkACL, string pwszRegKeyPath, string pwszQuickComplete);
    void Enable(bool fEnable);
}
```

IAutoComplete2.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

[Guid("EAC04BC0-3791-11d2-BB95-0060977B464C")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IAutoComplete2
{
    void Init(HandleRef hwndEdit, IEnumString punkACL, string pwszRegKeyPath, string pwszQuickComplete);
    void Enable(bool fEnable);
    void SetOptions(AutoCompleteOptions dwFlag);
    AutoCompleteOptions GetOptions();
};
```

AutoCompleteOptions.cs:

```
using System;

[Flags]
enum AutoCompleteOptions : int
{
    None = 0x00,
    AutoSuggest = 0x01,
    AutoAppend = 0x02,
    Search = 0x04,
    FilterPrefixes = 0x08,
    UseTab = 0x10,
    UpDownKeyDropsList = 0x20,
    RtlReading = 0x40,
    WordFilter = 0x80,
    NoPrefixFiltering = 0x100,
}
```

IAutoCompleteDropDown.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

[Guid("3CD141F4-3C6A-11d2-BCAA-00C04FD929DB")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IAutoCompleteDropDown
{
    void GetDropDownStatus(out AutoCompleteDropDownFlags dwFlags, out StringBuilder wszString);
    void ResetEnumerator();
}
```

AutoCompleteDropDownFlags.cs:

```
using System;

[Flags]
enum AutoCompleteDropDownFlags : int
{
    None = 0x00,
    Visible = 0x01
}
```

IAutoCompleteClass.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[ComImport]
[Guid("00BB2763-6A77-11D0-A535-00C04FD7D062")]
class IAutoCompleteClass
{
}
```

EnumString.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

class EnumString : IEnumString
{
    const int E_INVALIDARG = unchecked((int)0x80070057);
    const int S_OK = 0;
    const int S_FALSE = 1;

    int current;
    string[] strings;

    public EnumString(IEnumerable<string> strings)
    {
        this.current = 0;
        this.strings = strings.ToArray();
    }

    public void Clone(out IEnumString ppenum)
    {
        ppenum = new EnumString(strings);
    }

    public int Next(int celt, string[] rgelt, IntPtr pceltFetched)
    {
        if (celt < 0)
            return E_INVALIDARG;

        int num = 0;
        while (current < strings.Length && celt != 0)
        {
            rgelt[num] = strings[current];
            current++;
            num++;
            celt--;
        }

        if (pceltFetched != IntPtr.Zero)
            Marshal.WriteInt32(pceltFetched, num);

        if (celt != 0)
            return S_FALSE;

        return S_OK;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        current = 0;
    }

    public int Skip(int celt)
    {
        if (celt < 0)
            return E_INVALIDARG;

        if (strings.Length - current > celt)
        {
            current = strings.Length;
            return S_FALSE;
        }

        current += celt;
        return S_OK;
    }
}
```

MyTextBox.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    IAutoComplete2 autoComplete;
    IAutoCompleteDropDown autoCompleteDropDown;

    public bool IsDroppedDown
    {
        get
        {
            if (autoCompleteDropDown == null)
                return false;

            AutoCompleteDropDownFlags dwFlags;
            StringBuilder wszString;
            autoCompleteDropDown.GetDropDownStatus(out dwFlags, out wszString);
            return (dwFlags & AutoCompleteDropDownFlags.Visible) != AutoCompleteDropDownFlags.None;
        }
    }

    protected override void CreateHandle()
    {
        base.CreateHandle();

        autoComplete = (IAutoComplete2)new IAutoComplete();
        autoCompleteDropDown = (IAutoCompleteDropDown)autoComplete;
        autoComplete.SetOptions(AutoCompleteOptions.AutoSuggest);
        autoComplete.Init(new HandleRef(this, this.Handle), new EnumString(new string[] { "Administrator", "Clerk" }), null, null);
    }

    protected override void DestroyHandle()
    {
        ReleaseAutoComplete();
        base.DestroyHandle();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            ReleaseAutoComplete();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        return base.IsInputKey(keyData) || ((keyData & ~Keys.Shift) == Keys.Enter && IsDroppedDown);
    }

    void ReleaseAutoComplete()
    {
        if (autoComplete != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(autoComplete);
            autoComplete = null;
            autoCompleteDropDown = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. still it is giving the same trouble. I tried `this.AcceptButton = btnLogin;` in `public form()`.

Comment: @Mr_Green I'll attempt to create a minimal project that behaves correctly, and include it here, but it'll take a little while.

Comment: To save your valuable time I am sharing my project with you. Please [download it](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/87374848/SuperMarketApp%201007.rar) and test it.

Comment: @Mr_Green I was typing up more details. Unfortunately, because of implementation details, it doesn't seem to be possible to determine whether the auto complete list is showing, and because of that, it doesn't appear to be possible to conditionally suppress the Enter key. It is possible to implement auto completion differently, so that it would be possible, but that is a *lot* more work, sorry.

Comment: @Mr_Green I decided to give it a try anyway, take a look and see if it helps you.

Comment: These all stuff is really out of my understanding(as I am new to .net). I cant understand them in one day . It may take me one month. I will go through your code and others too (like @XIVSolutions and @Sami) to understand it completely.
Thank you all for so deep effort to help me :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the keydown event handler.

```
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //call original event handler. Remove it if you don't need it at all.
        base.OnKeyDown(e);

        //Insert your code here....
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Actually, I dont want to remove the original event handler. I just want to change the behavior of enter key when it is on textbox dropdown thing.  Like, i need to unhook the event in Initialise(). But i dont know what should i give to do that.

Comment: base.OnKeyDown calls the original event handler. If you want to change a specific behavior, you check what is in e, if you want to change it, before calling the original, you handle it, and return. This way if you have a special case, it is handled specially, otherwise the original is called.

Comment: Well I should have mentioned this before that i am new to .net.  I cant understand your explanation. showing a sample code will be better for me I think.(if you are free)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you have two issues.

First off, set the AutoCompleteMode property of txtUserName to "SuggestAppend" instead of simply "Suggest." This way, if the user types the first letter or two, the correct entry will automatically be appended to the txtUSerName.Text.

Next, modify your Form code as follows:

```
void  Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter))  //Invokes whenever Enter is pressed
    {
        if (txtPassword.ContainsFocus)
        {
            btnLogin_Click(sender, e);  //login
        }
        else
        {
            this.txtPassword.Focus();
        }
    }
}


private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtUserName.Text.Equals("Administrator") && txtPassword.Text.Equals("123"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Administrator");
    }
    else if (txtUserName.Text.Equals("Clerk") && txtPassword.Text.Equals("123"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Clerk");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter correct details", "Login Error");
    }
}
```

In the above, the Key Down event handling code tests to see if the password text box has the focus (meaning, the user has presumable entered a user name already, and a password, and is ready to submit the data). If so, the btnLogin_Click event is called. Otherwise, (meaning, txtUserName probably has the focus) control is passed to txtPassword to continue data entry.

UPDATE: re - Your comment:

Simply kill the logic in the Key Down Event handler like so:

Revised Event Handling Code:

```
void  Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter))  //Invokes whenever Enter is pressed
    {
        btnLogin_Click(sender, e);  //login
    }
}
```

Note, another minor improvement (considering the overall structure of your code) would be to use a combo box for selection of UserName, and set the autocomplete source to "ListItems" then enter your options the same as with the text box. This requires the user to select from the pre-defined list. This still has scaleability issues similar to the previous, but eliminates an unnecessary step for the user if they simply make a typo while entering User Name data.

Remember that users tend to dislike unnecessary interruption by pop-up messages. Allow them to select the appropriate "user name" from a drop down, type in the proper password, and move on.

There are some better ways to do all of this, but this should tune up what you have into working order.

On a final note, let me observe that eventually you will probably want to find a more robust way of performing this sort of validation. Any time you need to add users (which, in your code, appear to be defined more as "groups" you will need to add to your conditional event handling tree.

You might check into persisting usernames and passwords in an encrypted file or database, and load them into a dictionary or something at run time. Then perform a key/value lookup on user/Password.

Or something.

Anyway, hope that helps.

UPDATE 2: The complete code all in one shot. This should behave the way you are asking:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.KeyDown +=new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
        }

        void  Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter))  //Invokes whenever Enter is pressed
            {
                btnLogin_Click(sender, e);  //login
            }
        }


        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtUserName.Text.Equals("Administrator") && txtPassword.Text.Equals("123"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Administrator");
            }
            else if (txtUserName.Text.Equals("Clerk") && txtPassword.Text.Equals("123"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Clerk");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter correct details", "Login Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It has some defect, whenever i dont press anything in my `txtUserName`(or anything) and press `enter` it is going to `txtPassword` which I dont want. Instead of this I want it to do the btnLogin click event and show the MessageBox(error). I want to disable the `enter` key for temporary purpose when the user is in `txtUserName` dropdown thing.

Comment: The `Enter` button will work but it will not show the `message` --> "Please Enter correct Details" when focussed on `txtUserName` field.

Comment: It does when I run it on my machine. Look at the end of my answer, where I am about to add a code window containing the complete code for a form. The behavior, if you copy the code into your own form (and assuming the control names are precisely the same) should be what you describe you are after. Did you change the Autocomplete mode from "Suggest" to "SuggestAppend" as I suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hopefully it will not cause any problem on pressing enter while your focus is on txtUsername or else where

If you write `a` in `txtUserName` and press enter, Your `Admministrator` choice will be selected from your `autocompletecustomsource` using `regular expression` and focus will go to `txtPassword`. My regular expression is very flexible you can made it bit restricted  as following to match strictly from beginning and also can remove ignore case

`Regex rg = new Regex("^" + txtUserName.Text);`

```
    private void mainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter))// && !txtUserName.Focus())// && intFlag.Equals(0))
        {
            if (txtUserName.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                if (txtUserName.Focused)
                {
                    Regex rg = new Regex(txtUserName.Text, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    for (int i = 0; i < txtUserName.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (rg.IsMatch(txtUserName.AutoCompleteCustomSource[i]))
                        {
                            txtUserName.Text = txtUserName.AutoCompleteCustomSource[i];
                            txtPassword.Focus();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (txtPassword.Text.Length > 0)
                {
                    btnLogin_Click(null, null);  //login
                }
                else
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Please Give a Password");
                    txtPassword.Focus();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Please Give a username");
                txtUserName.Focus();
            }
        }

        //if (txtPassword.ContainsFocus)
        //{
        //    btnLogin_Click(sender, e);  //login
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    this.txtPassword.Focus();
        //}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but here, the `enter` button will not work when the user is in `txtUserName` field.

Comment: Right @Mr_Green. Sorry I could not understand? As this code has no does not have any problem with "enter button will not work when the user is in txtUserName". Can you try it please and tell me what does not work. I will make it hopefully. I have been doing lot of this kind of things.

Comment: @Mr_Green  "How to disable the keyDown event, when it is on textbox dropdown thing" what is "textbox dropdown thing". I can help you to remove and re add event also

Comment: The thing is that if I implement your code. then whenever it is on focus of `txtUserName` text field, I cant press `Enter` which I dont want to happen. you can take example as gmail account.

Comment: @Mr_Green. i could not understand why you can not press enter. Because where far I think this same code can work for gmail like account. However I have updated the way how you can remove the event and again add it

Comment: please read the question again. or try to test the code which I have posted in **hvd** answer comments.

Comment: @Mr_Green. No need to get rid of autocomplete its good. Just give a try to this code