# TextBox AutoComplete not showing suggestions properly

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I've a TextBox in C# Windows Form application. I'm using suggestions as user types in the TextBox using `TextChanged()` event. I'm creating `AutoCompleteResoure` dynamically everytime when `TextChanged()` is called. The problem is : let's say I type "j" in TextBox and it shows 3 results for it and Second suggestion is where I want to go. When I press Down Arrow key on keyboard to go to second suggestion all the suggestions get removed and text in TextBox is changed to the first suggestion. This means I can't go below first suggestion using keyboard because as I press Down key, text in the TextBox is replaced by suggestion and `TextChanged()` event is called and for that there is no other suggestion.
How can I go through all the suggestions using keyboard?
I've set `AutoCompeleteMode` to `Suggest`.
Here is the code.

```
private void searchTb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
     AutoCompleteStringCollection resource = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
     string searchTerm = (sender as TextBox).Text;    
     searchTb.AutoCompleteCustomSource = getResource(searchTerm);
}
```

I tried to consume `Key.Down` event when user presses down arrow key but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This should work..

```
//In KeyUp or Keypress or KeyDown Event
if keypress == DownArrow or UpArrow
  //Unhook TextChanged event
else
  //hook TextChanged event
```

Once have a look at this [`link`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12759177/1577396) too. [Somehow related]

Comment: Did you try with `KeyUp` event?

Answer (score 0):

Dont Use TextChanged event. It shouldn't be inside the TextChanged event. You should assign it only once...Instead Use this Code in Form_load

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     AutoCompleteStringCollection resource = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
     string searchTerm = (sender as TextBox).Text;    
     searchTb.AutoCompleteCustomSource = getResource(searchTerm);
}
```

Try tis..Hope it will  YouHelp