# How to set accept button to none while read the auto source complete in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, textbox, autosuggest

I have a WinForms form with a text box and a button (`btnLogin`). `btnLogin` is set as the `AcceptButton` for the form.

The text box is set to use Auto Completion. When a user selects an item from the Auto Completion list and presses `Enter`, the text box's value is set, but the `btnLogin`'s `Click` event is also invoked because it's the `AcceptButton` for the form.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Um. A bit more context please? Pretend that we're not able to see any of your code or your project, or whatever it is *you're* looking at right now.

Comment: I have set accept to One button control `btnLogin` it is working properly But In one text box I have assigned `autocomplete collection` While they suggesting those collection If press Enter I want to Add that Auto complete source item. But It will trigger my `btnlogic`

Comment: I've completely re-written your question, based on the comments you've provided. If it's incorrect now, could you edit it into a better form? But note how much more information is now being provided in the question. (And the title probably still needs some work)

Comment: thanks `Damien_The_Unbeliever`   for editing here what i want is exact like that edit text meaning.........

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your problem but it's working fine here, mind giving a little more source code to test?

Comment: I haven't write any code for this. Just i set my properties my `username`  `textbox`  property `autocompletecustomsource` to some `collection of strings` and set form property `accept` `btnlogin`    I have put some validations for email and empty boxes

Comment: My first idea would be to set the accept-button temporary to a new button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextBox autocomplete and default buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068783/textbox-autocomplete-and-default-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

I asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12759177/1577396) and got answer from **hvd**. [here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12760000/1577396). I hope this answer will solve your problem.