# Press enter in textbox to and execute button command

Tags: c#, winforms, button, textbox

I want to execute the code behind my Search Button by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I have the Accept Button property to my search button. However, when i place my button as NOT visible my search doesn't execute.

I want to be able to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> within my text box and execute my button while its not visible. Any suggestions would be great! Below is one attempt at my code in KeyDown Event

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        buttonSearch_Click((object)sender, (EventArgs)e);
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean when it's not visible?

Comment: Above is what i have tried. When my Button properties are set to Not visible.

Comment: I want to execute my button while its visible properties are set to False.

Comment: What UI technology is it? Winforms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextBox autocomplete and default buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068783/textbox-autocomplete-and-default-buttons)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You could register to the KeyDown-Event of the Textbox, look if the pressed key is <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then execute the EventHandler of the button:

```
private void buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
}

private void textBoxTest_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        buttonTest_Click(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly! FYI for this to work make sure your "AcceptButton" settings are set to None. I used this code while my AcceptButton was set to my button and it didnt work. Bad work on my end. Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Moreover you can set `e.Handled` to `true` to avoid the beep sound.

Comment: Hey, what is `this` in the byval for the buttonTest_Click? I've tried implementing your code in VB.NET but not sure what this means.

Answer (score 23):

Alternatively, you could set the .AcceptButton property of your form. Enter will automcatically create a click event.

```
this.AcceptButton = this.buttonSearch;
```

Comment: Yea this would work but one has to make an extra button for this and listen to `ButtonOnClick`

Comment: '.this' mean the current form probably, i don't know its working perfectly when the focus form within his textbox, when we try textbox.AcceptButton does no extension method.

Answer (score 4):

You can handle the keydown event of your `TextBox` control.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
    buttonSearch_Click(sender,e);
}
```

It works even when the button `Visible` property is set to `false`

Answer (score 4):

If you're just gonna click the button when Enter was pressed how about this?

```
private void textbox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            buttonSearch.PerformClick();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since everybody covered the `KeyDown` answers, how about using the `IsDefault` on the button?

You can read this tip for a quick howto and what it does: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/665886/Button-Tip-IsDefault-IsCancel-and-other-usability

Here's an example from the article linked:

```
<Button IsDefault = "true" 
        Click     = "SaveClicked"
        Content   = "Save"  ... />
'''
```

Comment: This is (in my opinion) the best way to do this, especially if you're trying to stick to MVVM principles as it just involves adding a single line to the XAML. But I think this answer could be improved by adding a short example (that link will die one day!).

Comment: Other solution works, but it seems to waste resources and this solution doesn't. Can somebody tell me how to do this in WinForms(CS file)? Can't find XAML File

Answer (score 2):

```
private void jobNoToolStripTextBox_KeyPress_1(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar( Keys.Enter))
            {
                searchJobNo();
            }
        }
```

sometimes you will have to use the Key Char class, worked the same for me

Answer (score 1):

There are some cases, when textbox will not handle enter key. I think it may be when you have accept button set on form. In that case, instead of `KeyDown` event you should use `textbox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void textbox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            //cod for run
        }
    }

    private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1_KeyDown(sender, new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Enter));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `WPF` apps  This code working perfectly

```
private void txt1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
     if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Enter) )
         {
              Button_Click(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
         }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

there you go.

```
private void YurTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            YourButton_Click(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please be sure to explain your source code a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

If buttonSearch has no code, and only action is to return dialog result then:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
```