# Activate button by Pressing Enter in Texbox

Tags: c#, button, textbox, keycode

Im new here in Coding and im Trying to activate my button from a Textbox by pressing enter. I tried to google for the Answer but Visual Studios say it doesnt work.
The most common Thing i read while searching for an Answer was the code down below. Now the problem is Visual Studios shows me the `Keycode`line as error. Can somebody help me figure out why its an Error?

```
if (e.Keycode == Keys.Enter)
{
   button1_Click(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

Comment: Which event handler do you use for textbox?

Comment: I dont know what that is, can you explain what it is and which one i need?

Comment: Maybe you can edit your question and add some more of the surrounding code, so that we'll have some more context.

Comment: I got a solution now. I will try to give more Information next time im asking for help here. Thank you anyway for Tip ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should register to the `KeyDown` event, in case you haven't.
   You might already have something like that in your code. It is done by either using the GUI options in the designer, or programatically using something like:

`this.textBox1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.textBox1_KeyDown);`

2. In the event handler, `Keycode` should be spelled with capital C, i.e.: `KeyCode`.

   An example for a complete event handler method:

   ```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            button1_Click(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: And where should i put the Code in?

Comment: What is the name of the method your code in the question is taken from ? My code examples should be similar to code that you already have (execpt the capital C and maybe the event/method name)

Comment: This was the Site i was looking on for the most: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975617/press-enter-in-textbox-to-and-execute-button-command
i figured out some lines of the Code myself but the KeyCode isnt working. But i ment like where should i put the
"this.textBox1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.textBox1_KeyDown);"
you send in

Comment: You can manually add it e.g. in the constructor of your class. But usually it is better to do it from the designer GUI: you select the `TextBox`, then double click the `KeyDown` event to create a code template for the handler (a method like `textBox1_KeyDown` above in your class).

Comment: If this is WINFORMS, then you do NOT need this code at all.  Just select the FORM, then set the [AcceptButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property to `button1`.   The `AcceptButton` property "Gets or sets the button on the form that is clicked when the user presses the ENTER key."

Comment: Additionally, instead of `button1_Click(this, new EventArgs());`, you should use `button1.PerformClick();` as this will cause ALL handlers of the Click event to be handled instead of just that particular one.

Comment: @Idle_Mind if I understand correctly the `AcceptButton` is global for the form. It seem like the user here would like the button clicked if ENTER was pressed only in a specific `TextBox`.